# How to create an overlapping float container?

Tags: css, containers

My site currently has a main content area that is centered in the page. I want to create a floating container to the left of this main content area, where I can put ad code to display an ad to my visitors. I want this container to be on the left side, somewhere between the menu navigation and the first blog post. Here is the code I have:

```
<div> <!-- float container -->
<div style="float: left; display:inline; width:120px;"><p>
<!-- my ad code script -->
</p></div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

I have been placing this code between the body tag and hfeed site tag, which gets the container outside the main content area. However, it simply places the container at the very top left corner of my site, above the header area. So, essentially, it's got it's own row spanning across the width of my site reserved just for the container, rather than placing it next to the main content area.

Can you please help me adjust the code accordingly? And where is the proper place to place this code?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider positioning it absolutely as such ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9kmc4mgc/)):

```
position: absolute;
top: 50px; // Or some number
left: 0;
```

If you want it to be displayed even when your user scrolls down, use `position: fixed` instead.

Or, since your ad `<div>` is already outside your content `<div>`, you could apply `margin-top: 50px` or some variation.

Best place for this would be in an external CSS file, but if you have to do it inline, just apply it to your ad container `<div>`.

Comment: Thank you so much!I got rid of the container and simply added the positioning (absolute, margin-top, and left 0) to my ad, and it did the trick! Thanks again! :)